# How to set different Theme styles for CustomControl?

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm creating CustomControl and the compiler knows that my Style for my control is defined in `Generic.xaml`... how to change it and point to something else?

Comment: you mean at runtime or before compiling?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Style Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
In your example I think you can do this way. In your `App.xaml` you create an empty style

> Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MyCustomControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}"

where `Style1` is the style in Generic.xaml. At runtime, you can change the style this way:

> var style = Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
>
> style.BasedOn = Resources["theOtherStyle"] as Style;

Or something like that, I didn't try the code, though.

Comment: All the WPF programs have an app.xaml. Do you use any particular framework? anyway, you can do the same in any xaml file

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer to your question for other people that might need it

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/pathToXaml/name.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
Style = resourceDictionary["StyleKey"] as Style;
```